# "Cannot test obfuscated variants when compiling with jack" error when building Android app with Jack toolchain

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to enable the Jack toolchain in my Android project by following the steps in this article https://developer.android.com/preview/j8-jack.html but as soon as I add

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }
    }
}
```

and run `gradle clean`, I get this error right away:

> Cannot test obfuscated variants when compiling with jack

I tried it with a very simple Android project and I still get the same error. This is a sample gradle.build file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

D'oh! The fix was really simple. Apparently Jack is not compatible with ProGuard and the line:

```
release {
    minifyEnabled true
}
```

enables ProGuard, since it's now called "minify". Switching it to `false` fixes the issue... I just didn't see the line because it was in a different section...

Comment: so you can publish this app on play store without proguard?

Comment: Turns out that Jack takes care of running ProGuard internally, so the only thing we have to do is disable the `minifyEnabled` flag so that ProGuard doesn't run twice.

Comment: ok.. do you know where mappings.txt goes using JACK.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38196100