# where is the proguard mappings.txt file generated when using JACK?

Tags: android, proguard, android-build, android-proguard, android-jack-and-jill

I have been trying to use the latest **JACK and JILL build system** to for my android project. I know that JACK process includes the proguard processing.

But after that i couldn't locate the **mappings.txt** file for **back-tracking stack-trace** of bugs provided on google play developer console.

Please help me **LOCATE mappings.txt**.

Another related question is if the **shrinkingResources** still works while **JACK** because **shrinkingResources** requires **minifyEnabled true** but **JACK** requires **minifyEnabled false**.

**Project Config--**

```
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
```

**UPDATE--**

Answer posted by T. Neidhart is NOT a working solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nowhere to find that mappings file as JACK internally process proguard and there are some issues pointed on android tools site while enabling JACK.

So for now not using JACK is the best option if you care tracing back exceptions in your apps.

Answer (score 1):

To enable obfuscation/shrinking with **JACK** you need to set `minifyEnabled` to `true`. It was unsupported in earlier versions, but now JACK has its own obfuscation and shrinking implementation (not using ProGuard at all) that can process some of the original ProGuard rules (for a complete list of supported options refer to [Jack obfuscation and shrinking](https://source.android.com/source/jack.html#shrinking_and_obfuscation)).

Once the configuration is properly setup, the `mapping.txt` file will be located in the same place as before: `build/outputs/mapping/<buildtype>/mapping.txt`

Comment: can you show me your build.gradle with JACK enabled.. your solution is not working as i said in question.

Comment: It probably depends on the buildToolsVersion you are using. In my project I use 23.0.2 with Android gradle plugin version 2.0+.

Comment: does it contains         jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }

Comment: This is for buildToolsVersion 24+.

Comment: so how you could use JACK?

Comment: "useJack true" for older versions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116445/discussion-between-arnav-m-and-t-neidhart).

Comment: I updated the answer. When using newer plugin versions (2.2.0-alphaX) you might need to use a different way to enable obfuscation (i.e. not using minifyEnabled true). For versions up to 2.1.0 the way as described in the answer should be correct.

Comment: sorry..it doesn't provide answer to me ... all the latest tools are out of alpha/beta... and now i need mappings file..

Comment: Well have you actually tried to use minifyEnabled true? When I do that it just works for me.

Comment: it won't let me build because JACK itself do the proguard and it will double the process if i set minifyEnabled true.

Comment: Maybe you can add the error message to the question. ProGuard can not run when Jack is enabled as no class files are involved anymore so I hardly doubt that the process is doubled.